During hot, humid weather, should I open or close upstairs windows during the day after running AC all night?
My two-story house is 1400 sq ft. During hot, humid weather I run the AC all day downstairs. At night I turn off the downstairs AC and I run the upstairs AC all night. Therefore when I get up in the morning, the upstairs is cool and dry. It doesn't make sense to open the upstairs windows at that point, only to let in warm, humid air, so I've been leaving them closed.
But by midday the heat and humidity have really built up upstairs. My roof shingles are black. There are gable vents at each end of the house and ridge vents along the whole roof. There is no direct sun on the upstairs windows.
I don't want to install a whole house fan or attic fan because I'm going to be moving.I'm reluctant to spend the money to air condition the upstairs and downstairs during the day. I have a dehumidifier upstairs but it adds heat to the space so I rarely use it in summer. I'm referring to periods when nighttime temperature is 70 or above and humidity is extremely high. What's the best way to keep down the heat and humidity upstairs while keeping the cost of electricity down?

If night time temps cool down, that is the time to open windows.  Using window films will stop the sun from adding to the heat inside.

Edited question to specify that I'm referring to periods when nighttime temperature is 70 or above and humidity is extremely high.

Hot air rises, so you're fighting physics to keep the upstairs air cool.
Black-out curtains may help keep sunlight out of the rooms.
Insulation under the roof and in the walls can help keep the hot air out. An attic fan may help reduce heat into the upstairs rooms too. But since you're moving, you've made the attic fan out of the question. It therefore seems reasonable to conclude that extra insulation (which is also a capital investment) is out of the question too.
Otherwise, if you want the upstairs cool-ish and you don't want to spend lots of money on insulation and built-in fans, you're back to running the upstairs ACs.
If you mostly don't go upstairs during the day except to grab something, you could try running the upstairs ACs on higher temperature setting to make the upstairs middling cool instead of comfortable cool, to reduce some cost.
I would not open the upstairs windows during the day. Though cool air falls, wind gusts could push the air around, perhaps when a downstairs door is open, and cause some cool air to leak.
I would open the windows at night, perhaps with some window box fans to force the hot air out before settling in at night with the upstairs ACs.

I think your idea of running the AC to keep the upstairs moderately cool, like 75 degrees, is good. However, in hot humid weather that means the upstairs AC will run all day. My house is very well insulated. Once the attic gets superheated, it doesn't let go of that heat for days. It's impossible to sleep up there without AC. I run the AC upstairs May through October. In recent years we've had heat waves in October here in the Northeast.

Does your roof have soffit vents as well? If so, the insulation may be blocking them. Alternatively, if the gable vents allow decent airflow and are big enough, I would try rigging up box fans over the gable vents to force air into the attic and out the ridge vents.

Yes, my roof has soffit vents. One is fully open and the other is half blocked off because I had a cathedral ceiling installed. The extreme heat in the attic began about 15 years ago when I had blown-in installation installed in the attic. The insulation increased the heat and humidity upstairs. When I had the cathedral ceiling installed I replaced the blown-in insulation replaced with fiberglass. But this year the first heat wave occurred in Maine, so this is a climate problem.

Correction: first heat wave occurred in May.

Soffit vents usually have channels put in between the rafters to prevent the blown insulation from completely blocking the vents and preventing air flow from the soffit. I'd check that the insulation isn't falling down into the soffits.

Woops, my mistake! I was referring to the gable vents above when I said one is half blocked. I have gable events and also soffits the full length of both sides of the roof. The blown-in insulation has been removed. Thanks for the advice to check the soffits.
